# Can I have a Guice abstract module with a constructor & local instance to provide a dynamic binding?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, guice

Can I have a Guice abstract module with a constructor & local instance to provide a dynamic binding? Can a Guice module have a constructor?

I understand that using providers/factory builder are better way, but in my case, I would end up creating n-providers or factory builder with concrete logic (nearly a hundred) for doing the same.

```
public class MyDynamicModule extends AbstractModule{
  private NeededInterface imp;

  public MyDynamicModule(NeededInterface neededImplimentation){
    this.imp = neededImplimentation;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(NeededInterface.class)
          .annotatedWith(Names.named("keyname"))
          .toInstance(neededImplimentation);
    /*.
      .
      .
      .
     *1000s of other binding configuration which are not related to the discussion**/
  }     
}
```

I know the alternatives, but I need to know if having this piece of code is wrong? If it is, I need to do a major revamp to replace just this one line of code, which in-turn would be a huge overhead for my application.

I needed to find a way to dynamically add a bind-configuration to an existing module. From performance point of view, the above logic seemed simple and straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this is fine. You won't be able to inject any dependencies into `NeededImplementation`, but that's fine as long as you don't need to inject any. I suppose you have some sort of conditional logic at startup that chooses a different implementation based on... something? Command line arguments? Properties file? You already have code that does this decisioning process; you should be able to put that code into a `Provider<NeededInterface>` without too much difficulty, but you haven't given the details. Are you proposing having hundreds of arguments to your constructor?

If you only have one implementation class, then you can just do:

```
bind(NeededInterface.class)
      .annotatedWith(Names.named("keyname"))
      .to(NeededImplimentation.class)
      .in(Singleton.class);
```

And you'd get the same result, if the class has a no arguments constructor. What is the reason you don't want to let Guice create the object for you?

Comment: the NeededImplimentation was provided by a provider The provider had provided the implementation @ my 9th processes .. i dont wanna create an instance in my 11th processes again. i just want to reuse what was obtained in 9th .. The provider.get() reads File system., so its a overhead which can be avoided even though it would result in tight coupling  between 11th n 9th ..[ @ this point, its Performance vs Design, i m planning to bend towards performance] .. its just that i have never seen a module with a constructor in any reference, which got me thinking!!!

Comment: @sakthiSakthiganesh it doesn't load it again if you do `.in(Singleton.class);` See: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes